# How to install metafun?

Tags: metapost, metafun

How can I install the metafun metapost macros?

I have tried to `tlmgr install metafun`, but it cannot find it. Also a search for “*metafun*” on ctan yields only a introductory tutorial on ConTeXt, in Chinese.

I remember I’ve had it installed previously, so I did a search for it on my OSX: `find /usr/local/texlive -name metafun\*`, which listed the file `metafun.mem` from an earlier TLBasic2010 directory hierachy under `texmf-var/web2c/metapost/metafun.mem`. (I am now using TL2012Basic)

I thought I could just copy it to my local `texmf` tree under `~/Library/texmf/metapost`, but

```
mpost --mem=metafun.mem file.mp
```

says it cannot find it.

So I would like to ask a) where can I find it on the internet, and b) where do I put the file so that metapost can find it?

Comment: Metapost in TeX Live 2012 doesn't read `.mem` files any more. Metafun is part of ConTeXt, so you need `tlmgr install context`; you call `metafun` with `mpost --mem=metafun` (no `.mem` extension required).

Comment: Thanks @egreg! Now I don't get any error about mpost not finding the metafun. Do you know if I need to still do something, because when I run the command as you showed, I don't see metapost loading the file (only: `Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004`). Also I get an error when trying to call, what I presume, a metafun function `drawpoints`.

Comment: I've added an answer showing that the necessary file are indeed read in; about `drawpoints` I really don't know: it is defined in `mp-tool.mpii`, but the details about it are surely in the documentation that you should be able to find at the Pragma-ADE site: http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `metafun` macros for Metapost are part of ConTeXt, so you need

```
tlmgr install context
```

For calling `metafun` from the command line, you can say

```
mpost --mem=metafun <filename>
```

although `mpost` doesn't load any more `.mem` files but instead inputs the corresponding files that would have been used for building the format, in this case `metafun.mp`. Indeed, if I try on a test file

```
mpost --mem=metafun test
```

I get in the log file

```
This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (kpathsea version 6.1.0)  15 JAN 2013 17:43
**test
(metafun.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/metafun.mpii
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-base.mpii
Preloading the plain mem file, version 0.63)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-tool.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-spec.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-core.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-page.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-text.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-txts.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-shap.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-butt.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-char.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-step.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-grph.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-figs.mpii)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-grid.mpii
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-form.mpii
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/base/string.mp)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/base/marith.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/base/string.mp))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-func.mpii))
```

and this shows that the right files are loaded.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can see also those files being included when I run `mpost`.  I’m not sure why it didn’t work earlier (maybe because of a same named tex-file along with using `mptopdf`), but now all is good. :-)